# Swiftmailer e-mail into Hotmail SPAM/Junk - SPF pass, DKIM, signed message

Tags: spam, swiftmailer, hotmail, dkim, spf

After a lot of researching and testing, the e-mail still coming into the SPAM/Junk folder of Hotmail. This only happens when the receiver, receives the e-mail at the first time. The content of the e-mail contains 2 links, 1 to a Facebooklink and one to the homepage. It also contains one big voucher (embedded image).

Below you can see the e-mail headers.

```
x-store-info:fHNTDlzCF8Nxw6HwcfGQy+S7Ax/lqLSm6/r2PsXEfEWQfMQRjp5FAY6oFLcDDmHWNUyGadvGiwKs+TutTkilkPOBB+E88DQ1fBrugEeofz66a1xPqllGuCI9jiWGqdk5pWM/fkUP2Jg=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 91.230.244.220) smtp.mailfrom=info@wervingsactie.nl; dkim=none header.d=wervingsactie.nl; x-hmca=pass header.id=info@wervingsactie.nl
X-SID-PRA: info@wervingsactie.nl
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTE7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD0w
X-Message-Info: 3c21WZ1hAls2HdAcRMKfViPUjnGuSLEFZkWg6RkqDXyGLT95Q/5VEBT70WXQSnVyTgl2xF8Bczb4CjSj30TvCttkpM4LzaUs8PbMIk4PUxFTl0ui3/Wsz0Gm3UgnZOZ1Yfg25aSTR8LWR6e6uFI/gjow8r/6Q8X95nu0ytSZvn0=
Received: from regulus.webleeuw.nl ([91.230.244.220]) by BAY0-MC4-F21.Bay0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Thu, 2 May 2013 08:40:36 -0700
Received: (qmail 29673 invoked by uid 10170); 2 May 2013 17:40:31 +0200
To: truetechnoandhouselover@hotmail.com
Subject: Verdien je rijbewijs terug bij Verkeersschool Breed
Message-ID: <1367509215.518288df620ce@swift.generated>
Date: Thu, 02 May 2013 17:40:15 +0200
From: Verkeersschool Breed <info@wervingsactie.nl>
Reply-To: "Wervingsactie.nl" <no-reply@wervingsactie.nl>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1367509229518288ed76500_=_"
Return-Path: info@wervingsactie.nl
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 02 May 2013 15:40:36.0553 (UTC) FILETIME=[63F65390:01CE474B]
```

- The IP (91.230.244.220) is on a shared hosting
- The IP (91.230.244.220) is blacklisted by backscatterrer
- Gmail: DKIM pass but neutral=bad format
- TXT v=spf1 a ip4:91.230.244.220 mx:mail.webleeuw.nl mx:regulus.webleeuw.nl ~all
- TXT spf2.0/pra ip4:91.230.244.220 include:mail.webleeuw.nl include:regulus.webleeuw.nl ~all

SPF seems to pass with kitterman.com
    Input accepted, querying now...
    evaluating v=spf1 ...
    SPF record passed validation test with pySPF (Python SPF library)!

This is how we sign the message

```
    // Sign message
    $smimeSigner = new Swift_Signers_DKIMSigner($open_ssl_private_key, 'wervingsactie.nl', 'april2013');
    $smimeSigner->setHashAlgorithm('rsa-sha256');
    $this->message->attachSigner($smimeSigner);
```

Does it solve the problem if we change to a VPS? Im very curious if someone can help me solving this problem. Thank you!